# R y axis normal

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis, scaling

I am trying to scale the y-axis of my plot to look like a normal distribution. For example, like this [plot](http://postimg.org/image/zc4c6v9mp/d3717f5a/).

The output of my code gives me this [plot](http://postimg.org/image/9f0xe7kej/ded1dc22/).

An equivalent "scale_y_normal" does not exist, so I am wondering if anyone has ideas to do this? I present my code for completeness, but this is purely a ggplot2 question so please only focus on the last few lines of my code. Thanks!

```
library(foreign) # load foreign package (converts data files into R)
library(survey)  # load survey package (analyzes complex design surveys)
library(ggplot2)


#-----------------------------------Download and importation function
download.nhanes.file <- function( ftp.filepath ){ 
    # create a temporary file for downloading file to the local drive
    tf <- tempfile()

    # download the file using the ftp.filepath specified
    download.file( 
        # download the file stored in the location designated above
        ftp.filepath ,
        # save the file as the temporary file assigned above
        tf , 
        # download this as a binary file type
        mode = "wb"
    )

    # the variable 'tf' now contains the full file path 
    # on the local computer to the specified file

    read.xport( tf )    # the last line of a function contains what it *returns*
                # so by putting read.xport as the final line,
                # this function will return an r data frame
}



#-----------------------------------Download files and creata data.frame
x1112 <- 
download.nhanes.file("ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2011-2012/GLU_G.xpt")

x0910 <- 
download.nhanes.file("ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2009-2010/GLU_F.xpt")

x0708 <-
download.nhanes.file("ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2007-2008/GLU_E.xpt")

x0506 <-
download.nhanes.file("ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2005-2006/GLU_D.xpt")

x0304 <-
download.nhanes.file("ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2003-2004/L10AM_C.xpt")

x0102 <-
download.nhanes.file("ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/2001-2002/L10AM_B.xpt")

x9900 <-
download.nhanes.file("ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/nhanes/1999-2000/LAB10AM.xpt")


#Rename to 'LBDGLUSI' (only 99-02)
colnames(x0102)[5] <- 'LBDGLUSI'
colnames(x9900)[5] <- 'LBDGLUSI'

#Add extra column for year
x1112[,3] <- '11-12'
x0910[,3] <- '09-10'
x0708[,3] <- '07-08'
x0506[,3] <- '05-06'
x0304[,3] <- '03-04'
x0102[,3] <- '01-02'
x9900[,3] <- '99-00'

#Name the varaible YEAR
colnames(x1112)[3] <- 'YEAR'
colnames(x0910)[3] <- 'YEAR'
colnames(x0708)[3] <- 'YEAR'
colnames(x0506)[3] <- 'YEAR'
colnames(x0304)[3] <- 'YEAR'
colnames(x0102)[3] <- 'YEAR'
colnames(x9900)[3] <- 'YEAR'

#Stack all data.frames on top of each other
final <- rbind(x1112[,c("LBDGLUSI", "YEAR")], x0910[,c("LBDGLUSI", "YEAR")], x0708[,c("LBDGLUSI", "YEAR")], 
x0506[,c("LBDGLUSI", "YEAR")], x0304[,c("LBDGLUSI", "YEAR")], x0102[,c("LBDGLUSI", "YEAR")], x9900[,c("LBDGLUSI", "YEAR")])

#-----------------------------------Plot cumulative fasting blood glucose by YEAR
ggplot(final, aes(x=final$LBDGLUSI, color=YEAR)) + 
geom_point(aes(y=..y..),stat="ecdf") +
xlab(expression(paste('Serum Glucose mM'))) + 
ylab('Fraction of the Population') +
ggtitle('NHANES Fasting Blood Glucose') + 
coord_trans(x = 'log10')
```

Comment: Please prune down your example to bare reproducible essentials.

Comment: I did my best to prune it down.